# Unclear how to specify multiple port mappings in Jenkins Docker plugin

Tags: docker, jenkins, plugins

I am trying to configure the container settings in a Docker cloud definition for a build agent, but it is not at all clear how to specify multiple ports to be mapped. Some of the options say to use commas, some use multiple lines, this one has nothing in the help to answer this question. The plugin docs are no help either. Do I need to specify the port:port definitions with spaces, commas or newlines?